# Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required

Tags: python, c++, pip

I am trying to install pylzma.
it's giving me this error but after 8 installation of MSVC 14.0 i'm starting to be really lost.

What do i EXACTLY need to do to install correctly MSVC 14.0 ?
do i need to add something to the path, if yes what folder, i have Everything installed on my pc so i can "search" a folder easily.

Don't just tell me "install MSVC 14.0" because it didn't worked.

here is the error given when trying to install the module.

````
Collecting pylzma
  Using cached pylzma-0.5.0.tar.gz (4.2 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pylzma
  Building wheel for pylzma (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\swann sanchez\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\SWANNS~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1dfh7_en\\pylzma_e57f9f3334e248288d2d208a7f8d25d2\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\SWANNS~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1dfh7_en\\pylzma_e57f9f3334e248288d2d208a7f8d25d2\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\SWANNS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-abs5fgab'
       cwd: C:\Users\SWANNS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1dfh7_en\pylzma_e57f9f3334e248288d2d208a7f8d25d2\
  Complete output (10 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7
  copying py7zlib.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7
  running build_ext
  adding support for multithreaded compression
  building 'pylzma' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pylzma
  Running setup.py clean for pylzma
Failed to build pylzma
Installing collected packages: pylzma
    Running setup.py install for pylzma ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\swann sanchez\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\SWANNS~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1dfh7_en\\pylzma_e57f9f3334e248288d2d208a7f8d25d2\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\SWANNS~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1dfh7_en\\pylzma_e57f9f3334e248288d2d208a7f8d25d2\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\SWANNS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-y5lmx0_p\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\swann sanchez\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\Include\pylzma'
         cwd: C:\Users\SWANNS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1dfh7_en\pylzma_e57f9f3334e248288d2d208a7f8d25d2\
    Complete output (12 lines):
    running install
    c:\users\swann sanchez\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:37: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
      setuptools.SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning,
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    copying py7zlib.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7
    running build_ext
    adding support for multithreaded compression
    building 'pylzma' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\swann sanchez\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\SWANNS~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1dfh7_en\\pylzma_e57f9f3334e248288d2d208a7f8d25d2\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\SWANNS~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1dfh7_en\\pylzma_e57f9f3334e248288d2d208a7f8d25d2\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\SWANNS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-y5lmx0_p\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\swann sanchez\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\Include\pylzma' Check the logs for full command output. ```
````

Comment: If you want to just use a prebuilt `whl`, you can download the appropriate one from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pylzma). Specifically, the one named `pylzma‑0.5.0‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl` and `pip install pylzma‑0.5.0‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl` from the directory it downloads to.

Comment: Are you running the build from "Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio" as this sets the MSVC environment correctly ?

Comment: What exactly did you install for `MSVC 14.0` (Can you post the link to what you ahve installed?)

Comment: @Axe319 I don't really know how wheel works, one of the solution i tried was to install it, it didn't worked so i forgot about it

Comment: @RichardCritten I don't know what is that, how can i activate it ?

Comment: @FlyingTeller I tried both installing it on Visual Studio and the Build tool one, none worked

Comment: To install you just enter `pip install C:\path\to\whl` in a command prompt. So if you download that file to `C:\users\swann sanchez\Downloads\pylzma‑0.5.0‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl` you should be able to just use `pip install "C:\users\swann sanchez\Downloads\pylzma‑0.5.0‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl"` from a command prompt.

Comment: @Axe319 It gave me ```ERROR: pylzma-0.5.0-pp37-pypy37_pp73-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.```

now what ?

It really doesn't like me....

Comment: @Oshida_BCF that is not the one I said to download. Download the one named `pylzma‑0.5.0‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl`. That one is built for `pypy`, an alternate build of python.

Comment: _"...how can i activate it ? ..."_ `Start menu > Visual Studio > ...`

Comment: @Axe319 Oups i though that i got the right one.

Thank you it installed, i hope i won't run into more issue with MSVC